# Resize image shape after cropping by UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, crop, image-resizing

In my project I am trying to crop an image using UIBezierPath and easily done by using CAShapeLayer and setMask operation. After my cropping operation the output is:

Input crop image:
[image]

Output image:[image]

Now, I am trying to stretch the output image and make this rectangle size image. For this I use a function and take all the pixels color in a array excluding the pixels which have clear color. For this I use this function:

```
public func getRGBAs(fromImage image: UIImage, x: Int, y: Int, count: Int) -> [UIColor] {

    var result = [UIColor]()

    // First get the image into your data buffer
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
        print("CGContext creation failed")
        return []
    }

    let width = cgImage.width
    let height = cgImage.height
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let rawdata = calloc(height*width*4, MemoryLayout<CUnsignedChar>.size)
    let bytesPerPixel = 4
    let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width
    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue

    guard let context = CGContext(data: rawdata, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo) else {
        print("CGContext creation failed")
        return result
    }

    context.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))

    // Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
    var byteIndex = bytesPerRow * y + bytesPerPixel * x

    for _ in 0..<count {
        let alpha = CGFloat(rawdata!.load(fromByteOffset: byteIndex + 3, as: UInt8.self)) / 255.0
        let red = CGFloat(rawdata!.load(fromByteOffset: byteIndex, as: UInt8.self)) / alpha
        let green = CGFloat(rawdata!.load(fromByteOffset: byteIndex + 1, as: UInt8.self)) / alpha
        let blue = CGFloat(rawdata!.load(fromByteOffset: byteIndex + 2, as: UInt8.self)) / alpha
        byteIndex += bytesPerPixel

        let aColor = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)

        if aColor != UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0){

            result.append(aColor)

        }

        result.append(aColor)

    }

    free(rawdata)

    return result
}
```

Then try to create new image to get a rectangle image. This code is:

```
public func imageFromARGB32Bitmap(pixels:[UIColor], width:UInt, height:UInt)->UIImage {
    let bitsPerComponent:UInt = 8
    let bitsPerPixel:UInt = 32

    assert(pixels.count == Int(width * height))

    var data = pixels // Copy to mutable []
    let providerRef = CGDataProvider(
        data: NSData(bytes: &data, length: data.count * MemoryLayout<UIColor>.size)
    )

    let cgim = CGImage(
        width: Int(width),
        height: Int(height),
        bitsPerComponent: Int(bitsPerComponent),
        bitsPerPixel: Int(bitsPerPixel),
        bytesPerRow: Int(width) * Int(MemoryLayout<UIColor>.size),
        space: rgbColorSpace,
        bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,
        provider: providerRef!,
        decode: nil,
        shouldInterpolate: true,
        intent: .defaultIntent
    )
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgim!)
}
```

But the output image is neither the actual image nor the rectangle shape. Final output image:
[image]

What is the wrong and what would be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Wow. Honestly? The first image is very close to a partial app I've written. (That's meant as a compliment! It's only the image, not what you are doing.)

**You could use a Core Image filter called *CIPerspectiveCorrection*.**

Basically, turn your UIImage/CGImage into a CIImage, convert your CGPoints into CIVectors, and call the filter.

**(1) Turn your image into a CIImage.**

Use one of these two lines below:

```
let ciInput = CIImage(image: myUiImage)
let ciInput = CIImage(cgImage: myCgImage)
```

**(2) Turn your CGPoints into CIVectors.**

CIImages have their origins in the bottom left instead of top left. (In other words, you need to flip the Y coordinate. Here's a sample:

```
let uiTL = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)
let uiTR = CGPoint(x: 75, y: 75)
let uiBL = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 300)
let uiBR = CGPoint(x: 25, y: 200)
let topLeft = createVector(uiTL,ciImage)
let topRight = createVector(uiTR,ciImage)
let bottomLeft = createVector(uiBL,ciImage)
let bottomRight = createVector(uiBL,ciImage)

func createVector(_ point:CGPoint, _ image:CIImage) -> CIVector {
    return CIVector(x: point.x, y: image.extent.height - point.y)
}
```

(You may need to test this to make sure the points are correctly mapped out. I typed the conversions freehand - uiTL may need to be converted to bottomLeft, and so on.)

**(3) Call the CoreImage filter:**

```
func doPerspectiveCorrection(
    _ ciInput:CIImage,
    _ topLeft:AnyObject,
    _ topRight:AnyObject,
    _ bottomRight:AnyObject,
    _ bottomLeft:AnyObject)
    -> UIImage {

        Let ctx = CIContext(options: nil)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPerspectiveCorrection")
        filter?.setValue(topLeft, forKey: "inputTopLeft")
        filter?.setValue(topRight, forKey: "inputTopRight")
        filter?.setValue(bottomRight, forKey: "inputBottomRight")
        filter?.setValue(bottomLeft, forKey: "inputBottomLeft")
        filter!.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        cgOutput = context.createCGImage((filter?.outputImage)!, from: (filter?.ciOutput?.extent)!)
        ciInput = filter?.outputImage
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
}
```

This should both crop and zoom the image to the 4 CGPoints you have.

Her's the link to the official [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPerspectiveCorrection).

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this. We want the image to be a rectangle width x height

```
  x0, x1, x2, x3;
  y0, y1, y2, y3; -- image corners
  rgba = your image
  image = output image

  for(y=0;y<height;y++)
    for(x=0;x<width;x++)
    {
       float xprime, yprime;

       xprime = bilerp(x0, x1, x2, x3, x/width, y/height);
       yprime = bilerp(y0, y1, y2, y3, x/width, y/height);

       xf = xprime - floor(xprime);
       yf = yprime - floor(yprime);

       // Now do bilerp again on the image pixels
       ix = floor(xprime);
       iy = floor(yprime)

       pix = bilerp(rgba[iy][ix], rgba[iy][ix+1], rgba[iy+1][ix], rgba[iy+1][ix+1], xf, yf);

       image[y][x] = pix;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but your answer isn't clear to me because I am new in ios field. It would be very helpful to me if you explain your code in details. What is bilerp(, , , , ,), rgba = your image, image = output image and what is the value of height and width?